# Equation involving the psi function

Tags: digamma-function

I am trying to solve the following equation, and I can't simplify it even further. Is there any approximation or solution to this equation?
$$\psi(r)+r\psi'(r)=\log r + 1$$
where $\psi$ is the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and $\psi'$is its derivative, and $r$ is a postive integer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "approximation or solution"  if you are also asserting that $\psi$ is a digamma function.  But it's not hard to solve the give  equation.  First, the associated homogeneous equation is $r\psi'= \psi$ which we can separate as $\frac{d\psi}{\psi}= \

Comment: By "solving", you mean finding all $r$ satisfying this equation?

Comment: @user247327, What?!

Comment: $\psi(r)+r \psi'(r)-\ln r-1$ seems to be $>0$ for all $r > 0$, so no real solution.

Comment: @Hamed, Yes, finding all $r$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: Sorry- I hate the rule that "you can only edit for five minutes".  I can never do it that fast!  We can write $r\psi'+ \psi= 0$ as $\frac{d\psi}{\psi}= -\frac{dr}{r}$.  Integrating, $ln(\psi)= -ln(r)+ c$ so that $\psi(r)= \frac{C}{r}$.  To find a solution to the entire equation, let $\psi= \frac{u(r)}{r}$ where u is a function of r to be determined.  Then $\psi'= \frac{ru'- u}{r^2}= \frac{u'}{r}- \frac{u}{r^2}$ so $r\psi'+ \psi= u'- \frac{u}{r}+ \frac{u}{r}= u'= ln(r)+ 1$.  Integrate that to find u.  That does NOT look like a "digamma"!

Comment: @user247327: This is no differential equation, a solution $r$ is to be found. E.g. if the 1 is changed to 2, a solution is $r\approx 0.103088$.

Comment: @gammatester, using matlab, the function is verified for large $r$. Btw $r$ is a positive integer.

Comment: What does this mean "*function is verified for large r*"? For integer  $r$ your function is $0<f(r) < 0.068$

Comment: @gammatester, I calculated the difference betwwen the two terms for $r=1$ to $100$, and as $r$ increases, the difference tends to $0$.

Comment: Yes, but I am pretty sure that it does not have a zero, e.g. for 
$r=100000$ it is $0.8333333333 \cdot 10^{-11}$. For large $r$ values, 
there should be some asmyptotic formulas for the polygamma functions.
Using Maple I get
$$f(r) \sim \frac{1}{12r^2}-\frac{1}{40r^4}+O(r^{-6})$$

Comment: You can rewrite your equation as $$
\frac{d}{dr}\Big [r(\psi(r) - \log r)\Big]=0
$$ at the same time for asymptotically large values one has $\psi(x)=\log x -1/2x-1/12x^2+O(x^{-4})$. You can see that alothough your function tends to zero, it actually never is zero.

Comment: @Hamed, Thank you very much.